# Pass translated value using ngx-translate in Ionic

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ngx-translate

I am trying to find a way to pass a translated value using ngx-translate in Ionic (I want to do it in `ion-card`).

Of course I can display the value like:

```
<h2> {{ 'DATA' | translate }} </h2>
```

But how do I pass the result as a parameter?

I tried:

```
<ion-card (click)="gotoFunction('DATA' | translate)">
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Why not [call the pipe from the component side in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913541/how-to-create-and-call-a-pipe-from-the-component-in-angular-2)?

Comment: why not use the functions ngrx-translate provides to you and then pass the result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing the translation in the component class, instead of the template, using the ngx-translate get() method.